# UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell with the UITableView still scrollable, but touches should got to the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

### What it looks like

This is what a single CollectionView cell looks like.

```
+-------------------------------+
| +-------+                     |
| | Image |    Some text        |
| +-------+                     |
|                               |
| +---------------------------+ |
| + Table View row 1          | |
| +---------------------------+ |
| + Table View row 2          | |
| +---------------------------+ |
| + Table View row 3          | |
| +---------------------------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

### What I would like to achieve

Depending on the data displayed, the entries in the table may or may not be selectable.
But it can always happen that there are more than three rows, so you have to be able to scroll the table vertically.
But now I would also like that for the tables where the individual rows are not selectable, a touch on a table row is passed to the CollectionView so that it recognizes the touch and triggers the appropriate delegate method.

### What I've tried so far

Setting `tableView.allowsSelection := false` causes the rows in a table to be not touchable. However, the tap does not seem to be forwarded to the collection view.

Setting `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` causes tap to be forwarded to the collection view, but the table view is no longer scrollable.

Returning `nil` in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?` causes the rows in a table to be not touchable. However, the tap does not seem to be forwarded to the collection view.

Overriding `func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?` and return `nil` when the rows should not be selectable, causes tap to be forwarded to the collection view, but the table view is no longer scrollable.

Is there any way to achieve this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach...

- leave all the table view cells "selectable"
- set `.selectionStyle = .none` and implement your own visual change to indicate selected
- in your collection view class add a `closure` to the collection view cell
- in collection view cell class, call that closure when a table row is selected

Here is a complete example...

**simple, single-label table view cell class** - change contentView background color **only** if `canSelect` is `true`:

```
class SomeTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "SomeTableCell"
    
    var canSelect: Bool = true

    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        //label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .light)
        label.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        
        // so we can see the framing
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if canSelect {
            contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? .orange : .clear
        }
    }
    
}
```

**collection view cell class** - with image view, label and table view... override `isSelected` so we can see that the cell is selected... `gotTap` closure to inform the collection view controller that a table row was selected:

```
class SomeCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    // closure so we can tell the controller that a table row was tapped
    //  whether selectable or not
    var gotTap: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> ())?
    
    static let identifier: String = "SomeCollectionCell"
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    var numTableRows: Int = 0 { didSet { tableView.reloadData() } }
    var canSelectRows: Bool = true { didSet { tableView.reloadData() } }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {

        [imgView, label, tableView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.centerYAnchor),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),

        ])
        
        tableView.register(SomeTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SomeTableCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // element properties
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .light)
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        
        // so we can see the framing
        imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        tableView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numTableRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SomeTableCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SomeTableCell
        if canSelectRows {
            c.label.text = "Sel row: \(indexPath.row)"
            c.canSelect = true
        } else {
            c.label.text = "NON-Sel row: \(indexPath.row)"
            c.canSelect = false
        }
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // either Always call the closure
        gotTap?(self)
        
        // or, only call it if the table rows are "not selectable"
        //if !canSelectRows {
        //  gotTap?(self)
        //}
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .systemBlue : .systemBackground
        }
    }
}
```

**view controller class** - we'll create 30 "data" elements, with the number of table view rows for each collection view cell. We will "disable" table row selection on every 3rd item:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var myData: [Int] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.itemSize = .init(width: 160.0, height: 164.0)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SomeCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SomeCollectionCell.identifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        // let's generate data...
        //  30 items, each with random 3-to-12 table rows
        for _ in 0..<30 {
            myData.append(Int.random(in: 3...12))
        }
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SomeCollectionCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SomeCollectionCell
        c.imgView.image = UIImage(systemName: "\(indexPath.item).circle.fill")
        c.label.text = "Item: \(indexPath.item)"
        c.numTableRows = myData[indexPath.item]
        
        // every 3rd item will have non-selectable table rows
        c.canSelectRows = indexPath.row % 3 != 0
        
        // closure so the collection view cell can tell us the table was tapped
        c.gotTap = { [weak self] c in
            guard let self = self,
                  let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: c)
            else { return }
            
            // tell the collection view to select that item
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
            
            // call custom func to "do something"
            self.myCollectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
        }
        return c
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // call custom func to "do something"
        myCollectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
    }
    private func myCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected item: \(indexPath.item)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I had hoped to be able to solve this with some setting I've missed, but calling a closure is not a huge effort.
Thanks for the complete example!